# Sort and access Data from a Table in a Dataset(C#)

Tags: c#

i got a problem with sorting my Datatable after inserting new rows. Im directly using the datavalues like this

```
TB_Test.Text = dataset.table[index].Test.ToString();
```

I have like 50 of those Textboxes on my WPF. I also want the user to be able to do + and - with the table rows.

How can i sort the Data after the user inserted a new row after a column like ID? I still wanna be able to access the Data via code like above.

Answer (score 1):

Set `DataView.Sort` expression.

```
DataView dataView=dataSet.Tables["tableName"].DefaultView;
dataView.Sort="columnName DESC"; // or "columnName"
```

Comment: I need to sort the table, not the view.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly sort `DataTable` using it's `Select` method. If not you will have to wrap the table with a `DataView` as [AVD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/142822/avd) mentioned.

[MSDN have a sample snippet on Direct Filter and Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zk13kdh0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). This returns a `DataRow` array.

```
dataset1.Table1.Select(null, "Id DESC", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
```

Also, [SheoNarayan's post](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article131.aspx) have some code snippets using DataView.

Which ever the approach, you will need to apply this logic when presenting data.